# Why are transients cleared prematurely?

Tags: transient

You would think that a transient set to expire at a certain time, would exist until that time. Unfortunately it seems  they are disappearing from the database earlier, both on test and production. As a simple example to see this behavior, try:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Test transient
Description: Show transients bug
Version: 0.1
*/

add_action( 'wp_head', 'doAnAlert' );

function doAnAlert()
{
    if( !get_transient( 'my_messageDismiss' ) )
    {
        //Transient nonexistent or expired
        ?><script> alert("This alert should also show again in 24hr"); </script>
        <?php

        set_transient( 'my_messageDismiss', 'dismissed', 86400); //Set for a day
    }

}
```

So what am I missing about the Transients API? The alert shows hours later, not a day later.

Comment: Any hit to your site however inconsequential will trigger that alert and regen the transient, you may want to use a better test, such as a check for `is_admin` to ensure that you're the only person checking it, and that no other calls or checks from your browser are unintentionally triggering it. Stronger test controls!

Comment: @TomJNowell I do, and this is just for purpose of a minimal test, and according to documentation it returns false *if the transient does not exist* : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_transient

Comment: true, it returns false, I was referring more to when your test is ran, using `false ===` would be better too

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR**

- Wordpress part of transient handling is solid, everything is pretty precise
- Transients use object cache instead of data store for non-default implementations
- It means that some back-end cache systems get rid of cache that hasn't been accessed recently
- Bottom line: it's not WordPress fault, it only depends on how your back-end cache is set up

You could get transients to be more precise but it requires back-end cache tweaking which I do not recommended if you don't know what you're doing, too much cache could have opposite effect.

**But even then, don't assume that it is 100% precise.**

---

From [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API):

> Everyone seems to misunderstand how transient expiration works, so the
>   long and short of it is: transient expiration times are a maximum
>   time. There is no minimum age. Transients might disappear one second
>   after you set them, or 24 hours, but they will never be around after
>   the expiration time.

You should **always** have a fall back method.

---

**Why is it happening?!**

> WordPress only invalidates transients when attempting to read them
>   (which has lead to garbage collection problems in the past). However,
>   this is not guaranteed for other backends.
>
> Transients use the object cache for non-default implementations. The
>   really important part to note here is that the object cache is a
>   cache, and absolutely not a data store. What this means is that the
>   expiration is a maximum age, not a minimum or set point.
>
> One place this can happen easily is with Memcache set in Least
>   Recently Used (LRU) mode. In this mode, Memcache will automatically
>   discard entries that haven’t been accessed recently when it needs room
>   for new entries. This means less frequently accessed data (such as
>   that used by cron data) can be discarded before it expires.

Read more from [this article](https://journal.rmccue.io/296/youre-using-transients-wrong/), it is very well explained.

---

**Caching?**

There are plenty of different systems but here's an example how MySQL database caching generally works. Im not sure how helpful it is to understand transients caching but I guess it couldn't harm.

- Data from each different query gets cached
- Each cached data gets a value (more complicated query `==` higher value)
- These values gets decremented (like a countdown timers if you will)
- Caching system checks these values in intervals
- If any of these values reaches to zero, that cache gets destroyed
- If same query is ran again, value goes back to initial value

So.. What could you conclude from that? There's no point to set transient that are:

- Too simple
- Not frequently used

Because these gets destroyed very quickly in most cases. I hope this gives you a clearer picture how caching generally works. It prioritizes frequent and complicated over simple and rarely used data.

**Note:** there's a lot of generalizations in cache explanation to make it easy to follow and understand.

Comment: Good answer, but this is somewhat incomplete - if transient is caching some request to some server that may take a long time, and ideally it would keep it for the full X minutes, before having to go and make that long request and download data again, how can we tune the cache so it will ignore transient closer to X minutes, rather than say, clearing it every minute and causing more long page loads?

Comment: No, it's not incomplete, this is totally another subject (even technology) and out of the scope for this site. If you want to know more about that, I would recommend to try another (database, caching related) Stack Exchange sites. Database and caching is so fragile and situational that you would usually need to hire a highly educated engineer to get it right (unless you have a small league site). You will never get a complete and **right** (for your situation) answer from online Q&A site. There's so many variables, database, software and hardware specs, traffic _etc_ you need to consider.