# How can we speed up wp_get_nav_menu_items()?

Tags: database, query

Using KCachegrind I can see that 2 calls to 'wp_get_nav_menu_items' (nav-menu.php) take 426ms.

(This is PHP5.5 on a speedy i7 Ubuntu desktop.)

Why is this method - which any theme would be calling at least two times if there is a nav in header and footer - soooo slow?

Is there a database optimization we are supposed to be using to make this WP query faster?

Comment: Cache the call, the result by use of Transient API. There are approaches for this already on this site.

Comment: @something If so why doesn't Wordpress do that already? Also, while that may be better, transients can get deleted immediately after... they are transient - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226200/why-are-transients-cleared-prematurely

Comment: It does not, so we have to do it ourselves. Well you can set `$expiration` to `0`, so never, and handle everything with the code you're writing for the caching mechanism. If transients get deleted in a unwanted way, then that's not default behavior.